# Using MySql in ASP.NET: Does closing a connection really release table locks?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I'm working on an ASP.NET application where, as part of some logic, I want to lock some tables and do work on them. The method runs in a separate thread running as a kind of background task, spawned via a Task. The problem comes in with the error handling...

The code looks more or less like this:

```
MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["prDatabase"]);
try
{
    connection.Open();
    MySqlCommand lock_tables = new MySqlCommand(Queries.lockTables(), connection);
    lock_tables.ExecuteNonQuery();

    // do a bunch of work here

    MySqlCommand unlock_tables = new MySqlCommand(Queries.unlockTables(), connection);
    unlock_tables.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (MySqlException mex)
{
    // Mostly error logging here
}
finally
{
    connection.Close();
}
```

Pretty simple stuff. Everything works fine and dandy assuming nothing goes wrong. That's a terrible assumption to make, though, so I deliberately set up a situation where things would foul up in the middle and move to the finally block.

The result was that my table locks remained until I closed the app, which I learned by trying to access the tables with a different client once the method completed. Needless to say this isn't my intention, especially since there's another app that's supposed to access those tables once I'm done with them.

I could quickly fix the problem by explicitly releasing the locks before closing the connection, but I'm still left curious about some things. Everything I've read before has sworn that closing a connection should implicitly release the table locks. Obviously in this case it isn't. Why is that? Does connection.Close() not actually completely close the connection? Is there a better way I should be closing my connections?

Comment: I've been experienced these before on  MS SQL vs entity framework. No matter if i call dispose() or  write code in   'using',still connected. then i had to write a procedure "kill every connection from this machine, except current". But same code without any problem when running on server, maybe because of network?

Comment: I can't test this of course, but I suspect that the problem lies in the connection pooling mechanism that keeps the connection _alive_ when you close it in your code. As a possible workaround to be tested you could try to call `MySqlConnection.ClearPool(connection);`

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping your Connection and MySqlCommand instance in a using statement. That will release the objects as soon as it leaves the brackets.

```
    using(MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr))
{
   conn.Open();
   using(MySqlCommand command  = new MySqlCommand("command to execute",conn))
{
   //Code here..
}

}
```

Comment: _using_ is just a shortcut for a _try/finally_ block. It shouldn't make a difference here See [Using C# reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx)

Comment: It makes a difference here because he didn't dispose he MySQlCommand instance. so the using block will take care of it. Using this method does not require him to declare the instance outside the brackets.

Comment: I will be more than happy if your suggestion fixes the problem. But I am very doubtful that this will be the case here. While you are correct that the sample code above does not dispose the MySqlCommand I hardly believe that this will unlock the tables. I think that the problem lies in the connection pooling mechanism that keeps alive the connection also when you close it in your code

Comment: Hi Steve, You could be right. But I think that the SQLCommand instance is still "alive" somehow. I also thought that since the SqlCommand instance takes a MySqlConnection as a paramter, then the MySqlCommand instance should fail. However this is not case, so I am thinking that the exception occurs after a successfull connection and a start of the execution of the command. Therefor wrapping it into using statements will dispose the instance and maybe abort/close/kill the query.

Comment: Let's see if the poster follows these advices and report to us of its efforts.

Comment: A _using_ statement doesn't seem to work. I've also tried calling connection.Dispose() in the _finally_ block and that didn't work either.